# How to add datatable in a list

Tags: c#, asp.net

I called a function in `BLL` from DAL that function output type is `datatable` and in `BLL` I want add it into a list how to do this?
in BLL:
My code is here:

```
    public static List<tbl_view> ListOrDefault()
        {
            List<tbl_view> load = new List<tbl_view>();
            tbl1 dt = new tbl1();
            dt = db.Fill_load();
            load.Add(dt.age, dt.famil, dt.name, dt.id, dt.field);
            return load;
        }
```

visual studio error in load.add

Comment: _"visual studio error in load.add" always mention the error on stackoverflow_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`List<T>.Add`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3wcytfd1(v=vs.110).aspx) takes objects of type `T`, in this case `tbl_view`, but you are passing single properties like `dt.Age`. You have to create and initialize instances:

```
load.Add(new tbl_view{ Age = dt.Age, Fami = dt.fami, Name = dt.name, Id = dt.id, Field = dt.field });
```

( presuming that these properties exist in `tbl_view` )